# React native paypal for ios not working?

Tags: paypal, react-native

I used, below link to integrate paypal to my ios application.
I followed the all steps in that.But it is showing  "Library not found for:lCardIO" error.

https://github.com/MattFoley/react-native-paypal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you missed an "Integration" paragraph:

> Include PayPal as normally, following their directions. Their integration steps and iOS SDK can be found [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK). After doing that, also drag MFLReactNativePayPal.h and MFLReactNativePayPal.m into your project.

**TL;DR:** [How to add PayPal-iOS-SDK to your project](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK#add-the-sdk-to-your-project)

Comment: Is there any solution for Android? Please dont tell us below solution: https://github.com/MattFoley/react-native-paypal